# doma2 can not copyResources to 'build/tmp/kapt3/class/main/META-INF/...'

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, build

I have a Problem with building doma Resource though I already have set dependencies,destinatinos, that kind of things in build.gradle

error message here

```
/Users/myname/Downloads/event_app_backend/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/main/com/event/app/backend/infrastructure/dao/UserDao.java:11: エラー: [DOMA4019] The file "META-INF/com/event/app/backend/infrastructure/dao/UserDao/getTicketCntByEventUserId.sql" is not found in the classpath. The absolute path is "/Users/myname/Downloads/event_app_backend/build/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF/com/event/app/backend/infrastructure/dao/UserDao/getTicketCntByEventUserId.sql".
```

i think package structure is ok , but doma can not find sql files.

how can I fix it?

build.gradle here

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.6.2")
    }
}
plugins{
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// テンポラリディレクトリのパスを定義する
ext.domaResourcesDir = "${buildDir}/tmp/doma-resources"

// domaが注釈処理で参照するリソースをテンポラリディレクトリに抽出
task extractDomaResources(type: Copy)  {
    dependsOn processResources

    from processResources.destinationDir
    include 'doma.compile.config'
    include 'META-INF/**/*.sql'
    include 'META-INF/**/*.script'
    into domaResourcesDir
}

// テンポラリディレクトリ内のリソースをcompileJavaタスクの出力先ディレクトリにコピーする
task copyDomaResources(type: Copy, dependsOn: extractDomaResources)  {
    dependsOn extractDomaResources
    from domaResourcesDir
    into "${buildDir}/tmp/kapt3/classes/main"
}

compileJava {
     // 上述のタスクに依存させる
      dependsOn copyDomaResources
    // テンポラリディレクトリをcompileJavaタスクの入力ディレクトリに設定する
    inputs.dir domaResourcesDir
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    // テストの実行時は注釈処理を無効にする
    options.compilerArgs = ['-proc:none']
}
compileKotlin {
    // 上述のタスクに依存させる
    dependsOn copyDomaResources
    // テンポラリディレクトリをcompileJavaタスクの入力ディレクトリに設定する
    inputs.dir domaResourcesDir
}

dependencies {

    // spring starter web
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    // doma sprig boot starter
    implementation ("org.seasar.doma.boot:doma-spring-boot-starter:1.5.0")
    // domaの注釈処理を実行することを示す
    kapt("org.seasar.doma:doma-processor:2.51.0")
    // domaへの依存を示す
    implementation("org.seasar.doma:doma-kotlin:2.51.0")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencyManagement{
    imports{
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.6.2"
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}
```

I tried to change copy destination some patterns such as

```
into "${buildDir}/generated/source/kapt/main"
```

```
// テンポラリディレクトリ内のリソースをcompileJavaタスクの出力先ディレクトリにコピーする
task copyDomaResources(type: Copy, dependsOn: extractDomaResources)  {
    dependsOn extractDomaResources
    from domaResourcesDir
    into "${buildDir}/tmp/kapt3/classes/main" ← here
}
```

but it doesn't work

[package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8MZt.png)

thanks !